# Executing several bash scripts simultaneously from one script?

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I want to make a bash script that will execute around 30 or so other scripts simultaneously, these 30 scripts all have `wget` commands iterating through some lists.

I thought of doing something with screen (send ctrl + shift + a + d) or send the scripts to background but really I dont know what to do.

To summarize: 1 master script execution will trigger all other 30 scripts to execute all at the same time.

PS: I've seen the other questions but I don't quite understand how the work or the are a bit more than what I need(expecting a return value, etc)

EDIT:
Small snippet of the script(this part is the one that executes with the config params I specified)

```
if [ $WP_RANGE_STOP -gt 0 ]; then
    #WP RANGE
    for (( count= "$WP_RANGE_START"; count< "$WP_RANGE_STOP"+1; count=count+1 ));
    do
        if cat downloaded.txt | grep "$count" >/dev/null
        then
            echo "File already downloaded!"
        else
            echo $count >> downloaded.txt
            wget --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies=cookies.txt --referer=server.com http://server.com/wallpaper/$count
            cat $count | egrep -o "http://wallpapers.*(png|jpg|gif)" | wget --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies=cookies.txt --referer=http://server.com/wallpaper/$number -i -
            rm $count
        fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most straightforward approach would be to use [`xargs -P`](http://offbytwo.com/2011/06/26/things-you-didnt-know-about-xargs.html) or [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). Generate the different arguments for each child in the master script. For simplicity's sake, let's say you just want to download a bunch of different content at once. Either of

```
xargs -P 30 wget < urls_file
parallel -j 30 wget '{}' < urls_file
```

will spawn up to 30 simultaneous wget processes with different args from the given input. If you give more information about the scripts you want to run, I might be able to provide more specific examples.

Parallel has some more sophisticated tuning options compared to `xargs`, such as the ability to automatically split jobs across cores or cpus.

If you're just trying to run a bunch of heterogeneous different bash scripts in parallel, define each individual script in its own file, then make each file executable and pass it to parallel:

```
$ cat list_of_scripts
/path/to/script1 arg1 arg2
/path/to/script2 -o=5 --beer arg3
…
/path/to/scriptN
```

then

```
parallel -j 30 < list_of_scripts
```

Comment: The script is 600 lines long., I'll see if I can cut it up a bit so I can post it here, there is also the problem of the config parameters, the script has several config parameters.

Comment: @kojiro I added a part of the sctipt so you can see it, I cant really use parallel here because all 30 scripts are different.

Comment: @user3084450 It's fine if all the scripts are different. Consider: `for i in {0..10}; do printf 'sleep %d;echo %d\n' $((i - (i%2))) $i; done | parallel` – What I'm saying is that if given no command to run, parallel runs each line of standard input as if it were piped to sh.

Comment: @kojiro Ok I think I understand, in ```{1..10}``` I specify amount of script to execute? and what is ```$((i - (i%2))) $i;``` for? and how do I specify the script name/path?

Comment: @user3084450 No, that's just confusing you. I updated my answer.

Comment: last questions: What is the ```- j ``` parameter for? and do I have to change anything if the number of scripts changes or anything? will parallel execute all the scripts specified in in "list_of_scripts" regardless of the number of files in there?

Comment: The `-j` parameter guides `parallel` in the number of jobs it can try to launch at once. There may be other limiting factors in the machine and kernel, so `parallel` may not be able to use all 30 jobs all the time.

Comment: I have some other problems, I posted them here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22926911/3084450